# JMS master/backup failover and failback configuration in Red Hat 7.2 EAP

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis, failover, jboss-eap-7

We use Red Hat 7.2 EAP. We have X number of producers on Y number of machines sending messages to a JMS queue on a remote machine. The JMS queue is configured with a master and backup. X number of consumers on Y number of machines are consuming messages from the queue. The master and backup are on different machines. When the master goes down the producers and consumers need to continue processing messages. When the master comes back the consumers and producers need to fail back to the master.

I have read the documents published by Red Hat multiple times and best I can tell this should be easily done. However, when the consumers or producers start up and the master is down they do not have any way to connect to the backup queue. How do people handle this situation? Do the consumers and the producers have to be programed to know about the master and the backup and then try to connect to the backup if the master is not available or fails? The documentation leads me to believe that failover should be automatic in that the master communicates the backup location to client when it first attaches. If there are dozens of machines involved how does the configuration of the master/backup get to the consumers and producers? Do each of the consumer/producer nodes have to be configured with IP addresses? How do people make this type of thing scale?

We currently set up the producers and consumers to connect like this:

```java
final Properties env = new Properties();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, System.getProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, PROVIDER_URL));
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, DEFAULT_USERNAME);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, DEFAULT_PASSWORD);
namingContext = new InitialContext(env);
```

Comment: Are you using JNDI to lookup your JMS connection factory and destination(s)?

Comment: Are you looking for help just on the client-side or on the server-side as well?

Comment: well the way we currently set up the producers and consumers are connecting like this: final Properties env = new Properties();
  env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
  env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, System.getProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, PROVIDER_URL));
  env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, DEFAULT_USERNAME);
  env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, DEFAULT_PASSWORD);
  namingContext = new InitialContext(env); for the producers. These are experiments that we have done. While we are able to get connections and pass messages i think we configured incorrectly.

Comment: Please note that clarifications should be made directly to your original question rather than in the comments. That way folks can just read the question and don't have to dive into the comments to get all the relevant details.

Comment: Like when we get database connections we dont have to know anything about the particulars of the database in the application code. or that the database is clustered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EAP uses a client/server JNDI implementation and JNDI connections are 100% independent of JMS connections. Since JNDI is the starting point for your connectivity with EAP you'll want to tackle that first. Typically an EAP JNDI URL looks something like this:

```
http-remoting://host:8080
```

Of course, if `host` is unavailable then the JNDI lookup will fail. You can address this in a number of ways the most basic of which is specifying multiple URLs, e.g.:

```
http-remoting://host1:8080,http-remoting://host2:8080
```

Other solutions involve dedicated load-balancers, DNS-based redirection, etc.

Once the JNDI lookup is complete you'll be able to establish a JMS connection. Assuming the server pair is set up correctly the connection will then fail-over and fail-back as needed.

Here is the `messaging` subsystem configuration from the default `standalone-full.xml` that ships with EAP:

```xml
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.0">
            <server name="default">
                <statistics enabled="${wildfly.messaging-activemq.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}"/>
                <security-setting name="#">
                    <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
                </security-setting>
                <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
                <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
                <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
                    <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                </http-connector>
                <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
                    <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
                </in-vm-connector>
                <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
                <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
                    <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                </http-acceptor>
                <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
                    <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
                </in-vm-acceptor>
                <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
                <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
                <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
                <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
                <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
            </server>
        </subsystem>
```

Here you can see multiple `jms-queue` and `connection-factory` elements with their respective JNDI bindings in the `entries` attribute.

If you have messaging clients running in remote instances of EAP and you want their JNDI lookups to be *local* then you can configure an `external-context` in the `naming` subsystem. This will effectively turn local lookups into remote ones. For example:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
  <bindings>
    <external-context name="java:global/jms" module="org.jboss.as.naming" class="javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext" cache="true">
      <environment>
        <property name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory"/>
        <property name="java.naming.provider.url" value="http-remoting://host1:8080,http-remoting://host2:8080"/>
        <property name="java.naming.security.principal" value="user"/>
        <property name="java.naming.security.credentials" value="pass"/>
      </environment>
    </external-context>
  </bindings>
</subsystem>
```

See [the documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.2/html/configuration_guide/configuring_the_naming_subsystem) for more details.

Comment: can you provide an example of the standalone-full configuration where the JNDI Connection would be defined?

Comment: The default configuration provides this.

Comment: The issue that I am having trouble understanding is how the http remote connection is configured so that it can be looked up in the JNDI context of the local jboss instance. I am sure this is obvious but I just cant seem to figure out the exact configuration where I set up an HTTP remote connection that I can look up using JNDI from inside my class running in JBOSS.

Comment: Your use-case isn't clear to me. Are you saying that your messaging client(s) are running in EAP as well? Please clarify.

Comment: yes. there are consumers and producers of JMS messages spread all over the network running in different instances of JBoss. How do those consumers and producers need to be configured so that they can resolve a connection to a remote queue that is part of another instance of jboss using an HTTP connection that is looked up locally using JNDI. I feel like there must be some fundamental piece of this that I don't understand but i have gone over and over the documentation for EAP 7.2 and I keep missing it.

Comment: Is it not possible for you to continue using `InitialContext` as you currently are but with additional hosts?

Comment: I updated my answer to provide more details. Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes it is possible to keep using the way we are doing it. What I was looking for was the correct way to do it while keeping the configuration bits out of the code. You know having the password and urls in the code as strings. I am curious about your statement about wanting the JNDI lookups to be local. Do they have to be local? You have been very helpful. Thank you very much!

Comment: What I am thinking about doing is having the master and backup servers have ServletListeners that would write their respective ip addresses into a configuration service upon startup and then having all of the processes that need to use the JMS get the configuration from there. Thus avoiding the requirement of having to keep a bunch of configuration in synch all over the network. Synching configuration has been a problem for us and as things change it around the network difficult to debug problems occur because of the violation of the first rule of computing(store information in only one place)

Comment: If you want to pull the passwords, URLs, etc. out of the code then using the `external-context` is the way to go. Your components can then make local JNDI lookups that will get translated by the `external-context` into a remote lookup using the configuration you provide via the `property` elements. You mentioned in an earlier comment that you wanted local lookups. The `external-context` gives you that. Of course, you don't *have* to have local lookups. You can use your existing method to perform remote lookups directly, but that leaves all the config in the code (which you also don't want).

Comment: My concern with having a "configuration service" is that it would become a single point of failure for any application that used it. If you augment your configuration service with redundancy then the complexity will almost certain begin to grow to a point where it would have been more efficient to just keep your existing solution where configuration is proliferated across many places. This is a common trade-off in networked applications. Not to mention you'll have to write code which reads and writes this configuration data in your various application components.

Comment: If you're determined to implement a configuration service you might consider something like DNS SRV records. That way you can benefit from existing infrastructure that is usually already designed with some redundancy in mind.